# Mathematica script - passing command line arguments

Tags: bugs, scripting

When using Mathematica script

```sh
#!/usr/local/bin/MathematicaScript -script
Print[$ScriptCommandLine]
```

and running it with some arguments:

```sh
$./script.m a=6 z=3 d=423 c=43 x=1
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Get::noopen: -- Message text not found -- (/SystemFiles/CharacterEncodings/ISO8859-1.m)
>
> Get::noopen: -- Message text not found -- (/SystemFiles/CharacterEncodings/ISO8859-1.m)
>
> Get::noopen: -- Message text not found -- (/SystemFiles/CharacterEncodings/ISO8859-1.m)
>
> General::stop: -- Message text not found -- (Get::noopen)
>
> Mathematica could not find its system-wide initialization file "sysinit.m".
>   The following places were searched:
>        .
>        ~
>        ./Packages
>        ./SystemFiles/KernelInit
>        ./SystemFiles/GraphicsInit
>
> {"./script.m", "a=6", "z=3", "d=423", "c=43", "x=1"}

With fewer number of command line arguments, this and any other script
do not causes errors. How can one fix this issue? I'm running `Linux 3.1.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Tue Jan 10 05:01:58 UTC 2012 x86_64`, together
with Mathematica 8.0.1.0

Comment: It fails again. I can overtake this by calling `math -script script.m {2,3,4,5,6}` but this is ugly. The file "sysinit.m" about which Mathematica complains is present in a standard installation directory.

Comment: I am sorry, you are right, I can reproduce the problem.  Removing one command line argument makes the problem disappear.

Comment: Another strange thing is that when using more than 4 arguments, the first element in `$CommandLine` (not `$ScriptCommandLine`) will be shown as `""` instead of the full path to `MathKernel` as it should be.  I think this is a bug.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Solution (tested on Linux)**

Use this as first line of your script:

```sh
#!/usr/local/bin/MathematicaScript -runfirst "$TopDirectory=\"/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/8.0\"" -script
```

If you installed *Mathematica* in a different directory, you have to adjust the path of `$TopDirectory`.

**How did I debug this?**

The first error message is quite clear: the system cannot open the file `/SystemFiles/CharacterEncodings/ISO8859-1.m` and obviously the system is correct, because this file does not exist in this directory.

You could now use `strace` to track down what happens (maybe you better redirect the output into a file)

```sh
strace -s 128 ./script.m 1 2 3 4 5
```

Looking into the output you probably stumble over the line

```sh
execve(

"/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/8.0/SystemFiles/Kernel/Binaries/Linux-x86-64/MathKernel", 
["", "-runfirst", "$TopDirectory=\"/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/8.0\"", "-script", 
"./script.m", "--", "./script.m", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

, [/* 54 vars */]) = 0
```

You see that basically you script-call is of course just a call to the `MathKernel`. If you execute this on the command-line, your script runs fine. This seems to suggest, that by providing 5 or more parameters, the setting of the `$TopDirectory` is somehow removed. Therefore, I tried to set it explicitly in the `MathematicaScript`-call which seems to work.

Comment: You can also use MathKernel or just math instead of MathematicaScript.  I think the system extracts the installation path from the first item of `$CommandLine`.  If this is missing, it can't find the installation directory and can't find its files.  I came up with the same workaround you describe (+1!).  Do you agree that this is a bug in `MathematicaScript`?

Comment: @Szabolcs I agree with Your explanation about the paths. I've just run this (oryginal version - without any modifications) script on a different machine and I didn't get any errors. This suggests that this could be system dependent issue.

Comment: @Szabolcs, yes, this is a bug. Why should the number of arguments be restricted? And when it is, where is it documented? I assume no one tested this at Wolfram.

Comment: @halirutan Just needed a confirmation from at least one person before adding the tag.

Answer (score 5):

I get two kinds of errors (different from yours) on Mma 8.0.4 Mac OSX, depending on the number of arguments:

(with the appropriate path for Mac OSX)

```
#!/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathematicaScript -script
Print[$ScriptCommandLine]
```

With 5 arguments, I get

> error: 14: Bad address

and with 7 or more arguments, I get a segfault:

> MathematicaScript(14538) malloc: *** error for object 0x70000037: pointer being freed was   not allocated
>     *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>     Segmentation fault: 11

A workaround is to change `MathematicaScript` to `MathKernel`, and use `$CommandLine[[3;;]]` instead of `$ScriptCommandLine`.

Comment: The workaround works for me too, on OS X (+1).

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce this exactly on win7 mma 8.0.1. `$ScriptCommandLine` is empty, while `$CommandLine` returns

`{"d:\\Math\\Mathematica\\8.0\\math.exe", "-noprompt", "-script", "./script.m", "a=6", "z=3", "d=423", "c=43", "x=1"}`

As a workaround have you thought about using environment variables to pass information to your script? You can retrieve the value of an environment variable with a simple [`Environment["NAME_OF_VARIABLE"]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Environment.html)

Comment: Environment seems not to be a good solution eg. when passing lists. By the way, the same happens when running: `$./script.m {2,3,4,5,5}` even when this script is empty.

Comment: I get the same thing both on Windows and Linux when using `math.exe` or `math`.  `$ScriptCommandLine` is empty.  However, if I use `MathematicaScript` (available only on Linux), then I get back the actual command line, starting with `{"./script.m", ...}`.

Comment: @mmal Why can't list be passed using env. variables?

Comment: @Ajasja I agree, it can be done this way. But I don't think its the best/proper one.

Answer (score 1):

I think this has been solved with the new command /usr/local/bin/wolframscript
as explained here http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/program/wolframscript.html

I can confirm that it works on MacOS Sierra with Mathematica version 11.0.1