# Windows command line arguments, stdin & stdout

Tags: output, scripting, input

Is it possible to utilize all three: command line arguments, stdin, and stdout all at once in script for Windows?  Unix is fairly easy, but I can't get the following to work with Windows.

Using the following as reference [args](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5347/mathematica-script-passing-command-line-arguments) and [stdin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3425).
I would like the following output.

```
_ FileNames[] | _ ToLowerCase@in
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On Windows, *MathKernel.exe* launches the kernel running within a window.  The standard output is redirected to that window.  To avoid this redirection, we must run the kernel as a console application using *Math.exe* instead:

```
 "C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.0\Math" ^
   -noprompt ^
   -script C:\Users\a\Desktop\test.m ^
   "data goes here"
```

Version 10 also has *wolfram.exe* which does the same thing.

---

**Update: Using DOSKEY**

As requested in a comment, we can define a Windows command alias for our script like this:

```
doskey _="C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.0\Math" -noprompt -script "C:\path\to\script.m" $*
```

If *script.m* contains this...

```
Print @ {"input" -> InputString[], "cmdline" -> $CommandLine}
```

... then we can have the following exchange on the command line...

```
C:\> _ arg1 arg2
abcde
```

... which produces this output:

```
{"input" -> "abcde", "cmdline" -> {"C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\10.0\\Math",
 "-noprompt", "-script", "C:\\path\\to\\script.m", "arg1", "arg2"}}
```

---

**Update 2: Using a Command File**

We can use a Windows command file to emulate the CYGWIN-based pattern established in the answer by @William.  First, we create a command file named **_.cmd** that contains the following lines:

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.0\Math" ^
  -noprompt -script "%~dp0mmascript.m" %*
```

Ensure that **_.cmd** is in a directory that appears on the Windows executable `PATH`.  The current working directory is fine.

Next, in the same directory, create a *Mathematica* script named **mmascript.m** with the following commands:

```
in := ToExpression @ InputString[]
If[Length @ $CommandLine < 5
, Print["no args"]
, Print @ ToExpression @ # & /@ $CommandLine[[5;;]]
]
```

It only needs to be in the same directory because the command file uses `%~dp0` to reference it -- feel free to change that to an absolute pathname if desired.

`mmascript.m` differs from @William's `test.m` in that it evaluates all user-supplied arguments instead of just the first.

Here is a session transcript of the command file in action:

```
C:\Users\wreach> _
"no args"

C:\Users\wreach> _ Sin[Pi/2]
1

C:\Users\wreach> _ in
4 * 5
20

C:\Users\wreach> _ First@FileNames[]
"AppData"

C:\Users\wreach> _ FileNames[] | _ "in // First"
"AppData"

C:\Users\wreach> echo "test" | _ ToUpperCase@in
"TEST"
```

Note how the last two examples use pipes to feed input to the script.  Like the CYGWIN example, the variable `in` expands to the result of evaluating a string read from *stdin*.

Comment: `InputString[]` doesn't seem to work in your example program if you attempt to assign the function to a `doskey` shortcut.

Comment: @William What was the nature of the failure?  It all seemed to work for me when I tried it just now on Windows 7: stdin, stdout, command line arguments.  I had to avoid breaking the command across lines since DOSKEY uses different escaping conventions than the command processor.  Double-check that the defined macro takes the form you expect by inspecting `DOSKEY /m`.

Comment: try `echo test | _ arg1 arg2` it fails in W7 because of the nature of the way `doskey` works. `'_' is not a recognized as an internal or external command.`

Comment: While `_ arg1 arg2 \n t` works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074672/redirecting-stderr-and-stdout-in-a-doskey-macro

Comment: @William Fair enough.  I've always avoided DOSKEY because it is not recognized anywhere but at the start of interactive command input.  I would just use a normal cmd file (e.g. create `_.cmd` somewhere in the `PATH`).  But we have now firmly left _Mathematica_ and are well into [superuser](http://superuser.com/search?q=doskey) :)

Comment: If you know a fix I will gladly post a 50 point bounty.

Comment: @William I have added a section detailing the use of a _cmd_ file to emulate the CYGWIN example in your response.  Hopefully this version will get you closer to your goal.  I have left out the pesky details concerning error handling, escaping, etc.  The offer of a bounty is appreciated, but not necessary.

Comment: It appears to only support one argument.  Is this intentional?

Comment: @William It accepts only one argument because I was following the lead of `test.m`.  There is no essential obstacle to adjusting the _Mathematica_ script to accept as many arguments as you like, and to evaluate them or not evaluate them as suits the application.

Comment: To clarify on your above comment.  doskey accepts `_ arg1 arg2` as arguments while you cmd script accepts only `_ arg1` of the 2 arguments.  I'm going to hold off on the bounty for now because I don't believe that is the intended behavior.

Comment: _\_.cmd_ accepts any number of arguments -- but _mmascript.m_ only looks at argument #5 (just like _test.m_).  To illustrate what I meant by my comment, I have changed the _mmascript.m_ script to evaluate and print all user-supplied arguments.

Comment: Do you know of anyway of getting this to work with the already open mathematica session so you are not opening a completely new session every time you run the command?   I'm not certain how to write to stdout and stderror with this issue currently.

Comment: @William Streams named "stdout" and "stderr" are available, e.g. `WriteString["stderr", "bad news!"]`.  As to re-using a session using only streams and strings, the only approach that comes to mind at the moment is to implement a Telnet-like protocol where _Mathematica_ and the other process take turns sending commands and responses back and forth.  _MathLink_ would give complete fine-grained control but would take more effort to set up.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of thinking and experimenting I have found Cygwin to be the the best option to support both multiple arguments and stdin.

```
alias _="/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Wolfram\ Research/Mathematica/10.0/Math -noprompt -script "C:/Users/a/Desktop/test.m" "$@""
alias ls="_ FileNames[]"
```

test.m

```
in:=ToExpression@InputString[];
If[Length@$CommandLine<5,
      Print["no args"],
      Print@ToExpression@$CommandLine[[5]]
]
```

Command line

```
_ FileNames[] | _ ToExpression[in][[1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is completely alternative solution that works similar to #! but for Windows.

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.0\Math" -noprompt -run "ToExpression@StringJoin@Riffle[Drop[StringSplit[UsingFrontEnd@Import[$CommandLine[[5]], \"Text\"],\"\n\"], 3], \"\n\"];Quit[];" %0 %*
exit

Print[$CommandLine[[6;;]]];
Pause[5];
```